# "Him that escapeth from the sword of Jehu shall Elisha slay" (1 Kings 19:17). Whom did Elisha slay?

Tags: history, hebrew-bible, 1-kings, elisha

We know the prophet Elijah called fire down from heaven, killing bands of soldiers; and we know he slew the prophets of Baal at Mount Carmel.  But his successor, Elisha, who had received the double portion of God's spirit, had a compassionate temperament who seems not to have been disposed to taking life.

Yet here we have the verse detailing the "swords":

> And it shall come to pass, that him that escapeth the sword of Hazael
> shall Jehu slay: and him that escapeth from the sword of Jehu shall
> Elisha slay. (1 Kings 19:17, KJV)

Whom, then, having escaped the swords of Hazael and of Jehu, did Elisha slay?

NOTE: Both Hazael and Jehu literally slayed people, so if one chooses to interpret Elisha's part as symbolic, one needs to carefully support this.

Answer (score 1):

1 Kings 19:

> 17 Jehu will put to death any who escape the sword of Hazael, and Elisha will put to death any who escape the sword of Jehu.

Whom did Elisha kill?

I do not take the part with Elisha literally.

Benson explained:

> God had appointed these three persons to punish the apostate Israelites for their idolatries, and that one or other of them should infallibly execute his judgments upon them:

> Hazael, however, began to slay them before Jehu was king, 2 Kings 8:28-29; though his cruelty was much increased afterward.

> Jehu destroyed those, whom Hazael did not, as King Joram himself, and Ahaziah, and all the near relations of Ahab.

> Elisha is said to slay them, either because he brought down, by his prayers, destruction upon the forty-two children of Beth-el, that idolatrous city, 2 Kings 2:24; or because by God’s appointment he inflicted the famine, 2 Kings 8:1;

God used Hazael and Jehu's swords to kill. The rest would be killed by Elisha's prophetic words.